# Authentication with passport (nodejs, express, typescript) gives me a 404, why is that?

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js

I'm in the process of learning how to use [passport](http://www.passportjs.org) and evaluating it for my personal projects. I wrote the smallest possible amount of code that I expected to get passport going:

```
import passport from "passport"
import passportLocal from "passport-local"

//...

const app = express()

//...

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

type User = {
  id: string
  username: string
}

passport.serializeUser((user: User, done) => {
  console.log("serializeUser", user)
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  console.log("deserialize", id)
  done(null, {id: 1, username: "sam"})
})

passport.use(new passportLocal.Strategy((username, password, done) => {
  console.log("local", username, password)
  return done(null, {id: 1, username: "sam"})
}))

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local"))
```

This is an API, so, it should just read and respond JSON. The frontend makes a post request to /login with username and password:

[image]

and the result is a 404. On the backend, I can see:

```
local sam monkey123
serializeUser { id: 1, username: 'sam' }
POST /login 404 22.516 ms - 145
```

What is causing this to be a 404?

Comment: Any luck?, I am experiencing similar issues. Will test your code see what I get.

Comment: When using your code minor modifications (changed deserializer to lamda expression) I get a typeError, that "this.authenticate" is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

After successful login, passport doesn't know what to do (or does something by default what you don't have), so you get a 404. You need to specify that as the third param of the login route (as it is in the docs http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-local/):

```js
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```

Or alternatively if you want to have an API:

```js
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({
      success: true, // or something to indicate to the frontend that you've identified the user
      user: req.user // or something (a token maybe what you'll use later)
    });
  }
);
```